# Libgdx save/load file in android external storage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to save a file in android external storage (sd card). I  used this tuorial :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0PtLexfBCA

than and this code

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/Settings.java

it's working on my pc. but no luck on android.

plz help.
thx.

Comment: On Android, where do the files end up?  And which version of Android are you running?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: Make sure you added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to `AndroidManifest` file.

Comment: i did test it on an android devices 2.2, 4.1 and 4.0

Comment: yes i did put that permission

Comment: At least with my device, I have to turn off USB file sharing if I want my apps to access the SD card.  I can then read/write with my app.  To verify with my PC, I have to re-enable USB sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to **get the absolute path of external storage** using a platform specific code in your main project and **then store your file on absolute path.**

To implement platform specific code use this link https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific and get path of external storage on android project using following code

```
String sdcardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageState().getAbsolutePath();
```

Save your file on absolute path of device sdcard.

Make sure that you have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Also provide a check that external storage exists on device or not otherwise it will work fine on devices having sdcard and wont work on other devices.

Comment: Is it possible to load an externa/internal image file (that wasn't built into the app) via LibGdx ? will it still use Android tools to decode bitmaps? Or will it do it on its own?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes its possible to load any external/internal file via Libgdx. until you know its whole path. Also you don't have to worry about decoding bitmaps it will load all the image files directly until they are compatible with it. By compatibility i mean that if your applications uses open gl 1.0 and you have not explicitly defined it to use impages that are not power of 2 then you won't be able to load them. So make sure that your external image is compatible.

Comment: How do you load images from the external storage via libGdx, and does it use the java-heap at any time for loading it, or everything is stored on the C/C++ world from the beginning?

Comment: String sdcardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageState().getAbsolutePath();

Is not working 

Instead use following

String sdcardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();